# flip with any degree of angle?

Tags: pytorch, transform, torch, flip, torchvision

This is the one of python example of flip the image with the corresponding box 
is it possible to write this as flip 20 degree angle or 20,25 or 45 degree angle? 
how to change this code to make any degree of angles???

```
import torchvision.transforms.functional as FT

def flip(image, boxes):
    """
    Flip image horizontally.

    :param image: image, a PIL Image
    :param boxes: bounding boxes in boundary coordinates, a tensor of dimensions (n_objects, 4)
    :return: flipped image, updated bounding box coordinates
    """
    # Flip image
    new_image = FT.hflip(image)
    #print('new_image->',new_image)
    # Flip boxes
    new_boxes = boxes
    new_boxes[:, 0] = image.width - boxes[:, 0] - 1
    new_boxes[:, 2] = image.width - boxes[:, 2] - 1
    new_boxes = new_boxes[:, [2, 1, 0, 3]]

    return new_image, new_boxes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`torchvision.transforms.functional.rotate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.rotate) to rotate image by an angle
e.g.

```
import torchvision.transforms.functional as FT
image = FT.rotate(image, angle)
```

You can also randomly select angle either using

```
import random
# randonly select angle b/w 20 and 45
angle = random.randint(20, 45)
```

or using [`torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation)

```
select random rotation b/w min and max degree
loader_transform = torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=(min, max))
img = loader_transform(img)
```

Comment: I have to rotate the box too